# Get recent media of users followed by the authenticated user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to create something like Instagram home page. How to get recent media of users followed by the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is look @ [these endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/) and get the media from each user.

Or you can go a more hacky route and login to the webapi and visit https://instagram.com/?__a=1 IIRC it will give you the feed or you can parse the index for the window.sharedData in the JS. EDIT: You of course need to send a request to login before hand.